# "Unresolved reference: text " error in kotlin android-studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Please help me figure out this Unresolved Error.

The code below gives an `Unresolved reference: text` as  error when tried to run.

The below code is of `BirthdayGreetingActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.birthdaygreetings

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityViewCommand

class BirthdayGreetingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val NAME_EXTRA = "name_extra"
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birthday_greeting)

        val name = intent.getStringExtra(NAME_EXTRA)

        birthdayGreeting.text = "Happy Birthday $name"
    }
}
```

The error according to android studio is in `birthdayGreeting.text = "Happy Birthday $name"`

The code of main activity is given below:

```
package com.example.birthdaygreetings

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }

    fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {


            val nameInput = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameInput)

        val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

        val intent = Intent(this, BirthdayGreetingActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(BirthdayGreetingActivity.NAME_EXTRA, name)

        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```

The code is in accordance to the older version of android studio, please let me understand how to run in the latest version of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Log the NAME_EXTRA to be sure you are using the same name.

The easiest way to do this would be to pass the session id to the signout activity in the `Intent` you're using to start the activity:

```
Log.d("MainActivity", "the name is $name")
val intent = Intent(this, BirthdayGreetingActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("name_extra", name)
startActivity(intent)
```

Access that intent on next activity:

```
val name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name_extra")
```

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) for Intents has more information (look at the section titled "Extras").